# Am I misunderstanding find_first_not_of?

Tags: c++, parsing, stdstring, string-search, findfirst

Consider the following program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string token {"abc"};
    const char* option_name_valid_chars =
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        "0123456789"
        "_-";
    auto pos = token.find_first_not_of(option_name_valid_chars, 0, 1);
    std::cout << pos << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `0` (GodBolt), while I expect it to print the value of `npos`: All 1 characters at positions starting from 0 are valid, so the "first" position of an invalid char is npos.. or am I misunderstanding the semantics of [`find_first_not_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of)?

Comment: `token.find_first_not_of(option_name_valid_chars, 0, 1)` = `token.find_first_not_of("A")`

Comment: @康桓瑋: Really? How come? The first parameter is supposed to be a string, isn't it?

Comment: The culprit is the `1` you pass as third argument to `find_first_not_of`, it specifies the count of characters in `option_name_valid_chars`. Removing that gives the expected result

Answer (score 4):

The reason of your confusion is that you are incorrectly considering the meaning of the third argument (parameter) in this call

```
auto pos = token.find_first_not_of(option_name_valid_chars, 0, 1);
                                                              ^^^
```

Actually it determines the length of the substring of the string `option_name_valid_chars`.

In fact the above call is equivalent to

```
auto pos = token.find_first_not_of( "A", 0 );
```

According to the C++ 17 Standard the method is defined the following way

> size_type find_first_not_of(const charT* s, size_type pos, size_type
> n) const;
>
> 4 Returns: find_first_not_of(basic_string_view<charT, traits>(s, n),
> pos).

As you can see the third parameter is used as the length of the string `s`,

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding `count`, the third parameter.

- What you thought it means: Limit the **haystack** - limit the number of characters of `token` to search.
- What it actually means: Limit the **needle** - limit the of characters of `option_name_valid_chars` to consider.

What you should do is:

1. create a [`string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) of your substring of interest (this requires C++17; otherwise you could make a copy with the `token.substr(...)`)
2. Search your substring without specifying the count.
3. Check against `npos`.

Comment: *"search without specifying the count"* sounds a bit wasteful.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat: I always do that. People reading the question should not care too much that the answer was written by the same person.

Answer (score 1):

As written in CPP reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of):

> Finds the first character equal to none of the characters in the given character sequence. The search considers only the interval [pos, size()). If the character is not present in the interval, npos will be returned.

In version 2 of the function, you may specify the count of you characters for comparison. So, in your case 1. With that, you will not compare to

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"0123456789"
"_-"
```

but only to 'A'.

And so, 0 will be returned, since 0 is the index of the first none 'a' character.

Remove the count. Then it will work.